# TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!canvas"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with python version 3.7.1 to build a snake game using tkinter package. Well, it's more like copying other person's code from github then modified it myself. The goal is to make a snake game that is played by the system for 10 times. So after the first game is finished, the tkinter frame will close and another one will pop up and repeat until 10 times. The problem is that every time the game's finished and the frame's closed, the system will give a warning, and after 5 or 6 iterations the system will forced stop and gave the same error message as the warning.

This is the warning:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-18-b0768e06fac0>", line 132, in tick
    self.render()
  File "<ipython-input-18-b0768e06fac0>", line 95, in render
    self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2514, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!canvas"
```

This is the error message that made the system force stop the process:

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-d3ce3af75353> in <module>
      1 bots = []
      2 for i in range(0, 10):
----> 3     bots.append(snake_bot((i + 1), 10))

<ipython-input-18-b0768e06fac0> in __init__(self, bot_id, speed)
     75         self.direction = random.choice(availabel_directions)
     76 
---> 77         self.start()
     78 
     79     def draw_rect(self, x, y, color='#00f'):

<ipython-input-18-b0768e06fac0> in start(self)
    134 
    135     def start(self):
--> 136         self.tick()
    137         self.window.mainloop()
    138 

<ipython-input-18-b0768e06fac0> in tick(self)
    130         self.move_snake(self.direction)
    131         self.check_food()
--> 132         self.render()
    133         self.window.after(int(1000 / self.speed), self.tick)
    134 

<ipython-input-18-b0768e06fac0> in render(self)
     93 
     94     def render(self):
---> 95         self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
     96 
     97         for x in range(0, self.X):

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in delete(self, *args)
   2512     def delete(self, *args):
   2513         """Delete items identified by all tag or ids contained in ARGS."""
-> 2514         self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
   2515     def dtag(self, *args):
   2516         """Delete tag or id given as last arguments in ARGS from items

TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!canvas"
```

This is the code that I have modified:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH
import tkinter
from collections import deque
from random import randint
import random
from IPython.display import clear_output

class snake_bot():
    def __init__(self, bot_id, speed):
        #
        self.bot_id = bot_id
        self.speed = speed

        self.X = 30
        self.Y = 20
        self.BLOCK_SIZE = 20

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(self.X * self.BLOCK_SIZE, self.Y * self.BLOCK_SIZE))
        self.window.resizable(False, False)

        self.frame = Frame(self.window)
        self.frame.master.title('Snake Bot - ID - ' +str(self.bot_id))
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.VALID_DIRECTIONS = {
            'Left': set(('Up', 'Down')),
            'Right': set(('Up', 'Down')),
            'Up': set(('Left', 'Right')),
            'Down': set(('Left', 'Right'))
        }

        self.MOVEMENTS = {
            'Left': lambda x, y: (x - 1, y),
            'Right': lambda x, y: (x + 1, y),
            'Up': lambda x, y: (x, y - 1),
            'Down': lambda x, y: (x, y + 1)
        }

        self.score = 0

        randX = randint(0, (self.X - 2))
        randY = randint(0, (self.Y - 2))
        coin_flip = randint(1, 2)
        if(coin_flip == 1):
            #X
            coin_flip = randint(1, 2)
            if(coin_flip == 1):
                #-
                self.snake = deque(((randX, randY), ((randX-1), randY))) 
            else:
                #+
                self.snake = deque(((randX, randY), ((randX+1), randY))) 
        else:
            #Y
            coin_flip = randint(1, 2)
            if(coin_flip == 1):
                #-
                self.snake = deque(((randX, randY), (randX, (randY-1)))) 
            else:
                #+
                self.snake = deque(((randX, randY), (randX, (randY+1)))) 

        in_s = True
        while(in_s == True):
            self.food = (randint(0, (self.X - 1)), randint(0, (self.Y - 1)))
            if self.food not in self.snake:
                in_s = False

        self.moves = deque()
        availabel_directions = ['Down', 'Up', 'Right', 'Left']
        self.direction = random.choice(availabel_directions)

        self.start()

    def draw_rect(self, x, y, color='#00f'):
        self.x1 = x * self.BLOCK_SIZE
        self.y1 = y * self.BLOCK_SIZE
        self.x2 = self.x1 + self.BLOCK_SIZE
        self.y2 = self.y1 + self.BLOCK_SIZE 
        return self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill=color)

    def draw_background(self, x, y):
        self.x1 = x * self.BLOCK_SIZE
        self.y1 = y * self.BLOCK_SIZE
        self.x2 = self.x1 + self.BLOCK_SIZE
        self.y2 = self.y1 + self.BLOCK_SIZE
        return self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill='white')

    def render(self):
        self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)

        for x in range(0, self.X):
            for y in range(0, self.Y):
                self.draw_background(x, y)
        for self.x, self.y in self.snake:
            self.draw_rect(self.x, self.y, color='#00f')
        self.x, self.y = self.food
        self.draw_rect(self.x, self.y, color='#f00')

    def create_food(self):
        self.s = set(self.snake)
        while True:
            self.food = randint(0, self.X - 1), randint(0, self.Y - 1)
            if self.food not in self.s:
                return self.food

    def check_food(self):
        self.s = set(self.snake)
        if self.food in self.s:
            self.increase_score()
            self.food = self.create_food()
        else:
            self.snake.popleft()

    def random_direction(self):
        self._direction = self.moves[-1] if self.moves else self.direction 
        availabel_directions = ['Down', 'Up', 'Right', 'Left']
        self.key = random.choice(availabel_directions)
        if self.key in self.VALID_DIRECTIONS[self._direction]:
            self.moves.append(self.key)

    def tick(self):
        self.random_direction()
        self.direction = self.moves.popleft() if self.moves else self.direction
        self.move_snake(self.direction)
        self.check_food()
        self.render()
        self.window.after(int(1000 / self.speed), self.tick)

    def start(self):
        self.tick()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def increase_score(self):
        self.score += 1
        if not self.score % 5:
            # increase speed after the snake eats 5 times
            self.speed += 2
        clear_output()
        print('ID - ', self.bot_id, 'score:', self.score, 'speed:', self.speed)

    def move_snake(self, direction):
        self.x, self.y = self.snake[-1]
        self.next_point = self.MOVEMENTS[self.direction](self.x, self.y)

        self.s = set(self.snake)
        if self.next_point in self.s:
            self.window.destroy()
            clear_output()
            print('You just ate yourself')
            print('ID - ', self.bot_id, 'score:', self.score, 'speed:', self.speed)
        if self.x < 0 or self.x >= self.X or self.y < 0 or self.y >= self.Y:
            self.window.destroy()
            clear_output()
            print('You crashed into a wall')
            print('ID - ', self.bot_id, 'score:', self.score, 'speed:', self.speed)

        self.snake.append(self.next_point)

bots = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    bots.append(snake_bot((i + 1), 10))
```

I've tried to find the solution but until now I'm still stuck. I hope someone could help me to find the solution to this problem. Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you don't really control the self.windows and

self.canvas existence.

I make two change and now the script apparently work....apparently!

```
def render(self):

    try:
        self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)

        for x in range(0, self.X):
            for y in range(0, self.Y):
                self.draw_background(x, y)
        for self.x, self.y in self.snake:
            self.draw_rect(self.x, self.y, color='#00f')
        self.x, self.y = self.food
        self.draw_rect(self.x, self.y, color='#f00')
    except:
        pass
```

and here

```
def move_snake(self, direction):
    self.x, self.y = self.snake[-1]
    self.next_point = self.MOVEMENTS[self.direction](self.x, self.y)

    self.s = set(self.snake)
    if self.next_point in self.s:
        self.window.destroy()
        clear_output()
        print('You just ate yourself')
        print('ID - ', self.bot_id, 'score:', self.score, 'speed:', self.speed)
    if self.x < 0 or self.x >= self.X or self.y < 0 or self.y >= self.Y:
        try:
            self.window.destroy()
            clear_output()
            print('You crashed into a wall')
            print('ID - ', self.bot_id, 'score:', self.score, 'speed:', self.speed)
        except:
            pass
```

and i get this

You just ate yourself

ID -  1 score: 0 speed: 10

You just ate yourself

ID -  2 score: 0 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  3 score: 0 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  4 score: 1 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  5 score: 0 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  6 score: 0 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  7 score: 0 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  8 score: 1 speed: 10

You just ate yourself

ID -  9 score: 0 speed: 10

You crashed into a wall

ID -  10 score: 0 speed: 10

Comment: I just tried this and apparently it works as well. I did try the 'try except' as well in the render function, but I used 'None' instead of 'pass' and I still got the same error message. I don't know why changing it to 'pass' fix the problem, but anyhow, thank you so much!